# How do you stretch a sine graph while retaining resolution in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, p5.js

I have written a sine graph plotting program. It works apart from the fact that the graph is choppy. I need to make it so that I can stretch the line without changing the x values of the points.

Here is the project: https://editor.p5js.org/korczaka6052/sketches/49-sJW6wz

```js
let slidery;
let sliderx
width_ = 800
height_ = 400
linelen = width_ - 100

function setup() {
  createCanvas(width_, height_);
  //create sliders controlling xstep and ystep
  slidery = createSlider(0, 100);
  slidery.position(10, 10);
  slidery.style('width', '200px');
  sliderx = createSlider(0, 100);
  sliderx.position(250, 10);
  sliderx.style('width', '200px');
}


class createPoint { //create a point with its own x and y coordinate, ik could use vectors
  constructor(x_, y_) {
    this.x = 50 + x_;
    this.y = height_ / 2 - y_;
  }
  show() {
    fill(0)
    circle(this.x, this.y, 1)
  }
  writetext() {
    textSize(10)
    text(this.x, this.x, height / 2 + 10)
  }
}

//where all the points will be stored
points = [];
xstep = 1;
ystep = 50;
looper = 0;

function draw() {
  //set xstep and ystep to their slider values
  ystep = slidery.value()
  xstep = sliderx.value()
  stroke(0)
  background(220);

  //create graph lines
  line(50, height / 2, width - 50, height / 2);
  line(50, 50, 50, height - 50);

  //for every [ystep] pixels calculate y based off equation
  for (i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
    points[i] = new createPoint(i * xstep, sin(i) * ystep); //creates that point as object with x and y value, y = sin(x) 
  }

  //create line between current and previous point
  for (i = 1; i < 800; i++) {
    stroke(255, 0, 0)
    //create only if point is inside canvas
    if (points[i - 1].y < height) {
      line(points[i - 1].x, points[i - 1].y, points[i].x, points[i].y)
    }
  }

  //create white borders to cut off extreme points
  noStroke(0)
  fill(220)
  rect(width - 50, 0, width, height)
  rect(width, height, width - 50, 0)
  rect(0, 0, width, 50)
  rect(0, height, width, -50)
  looper++
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I am relatively new to p5.js so please excuse bad code.

Comment: FYI, when asking questions on StackOverflow it is preferable to embed the code in the question, ideally as a runnable snippet when it is JavaScript based. Links to external sites can break, or the code there may change over time. I've updated your question.

Comment: @PaulWheeler Thanks, did not know you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your line is choppy is because when `xstep` is greater than 1, the horizontal distance between each pair of points is relatively large. When you start out with an `xstep` of 50 you may have 800 points but only the first 16 or so are actually on the screen. Instead of advancing your x coordinate by `xstep` you should just advance by `1` (i.e., use `i` for the first argument to `createPoint` instead of `i * xstep`). When you do so, in order to draw the desired curve, you need to change the input to the `sin()` function used to calculate the corresponding `y` value. Because when you move forward by one pixel you are only moving to the right by `1 / xstep` in the graph coordinate system, you simply need to use `sin(i / xstep)` instead of `sin(i)`.

```js
let slidery;
let sliderx;
let smooothCheckbox;
const width_ = 800;
const height_ = 400;
const linelen = width_ - 100;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(width_, height_);
  //create sliders controlling xstep and ystep
  slidery = createSlider(0, 100);
  slidery.position(10, 10);
  slidery.style('width', '200px');
  sliderx = createSlider(0, 100);
  sliderx.position(250, 10);
  sliderx.style('width', '200px');
  
  smoothCheckbox = createCheckbox('Smooth?', true);
  smoothCheckbox.position(10, 30);
}


class createPoint { //create a point with its own x and y coordinate, ik could use vectors
  constructor(x_, y_) {
    this.x = 50 + x_;
    this.y = height_ / 2 - y_;
  }
  show() {
    fill(0)
    circle(this.x, this.y, 1)
  }
  writetext() {
    textSize(10)
    text(this.x, this.x, height / 2 + 10)
  }
}

//where all the points will be stored
let points = [];
let xstep = 1;
let ystep = 50;
let looper = 0;

function draw() {
  //set xstep and ystep to their slider values
  ystep = slidery.value();
  xstep = sliderx.value();
  stroke(0);
  background(220);

  //create graph lines
  line(50, height / 2, width - 50, height / 2);
  line(50, 50, 50, height - 50);

  //for every [xstep] pixels calculate y based off equation
  for (i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
    if (smoothCheckbox.checked()) {
      points[i] = new createPoint(i, sin(i / xstep) * ystep); //creates that point as object with x and y value, y = sin(x) 
    } else {
      points[i] = new createPoint(i * xstep, sin(i) * ystep);
    }
  }

  //create line between current and previous point
  for (i = 1; i < 800; i++) {
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    //create only if point is inside canvas
    if (points[i - 1].y < height) {
      line(points[i - 1].x, points[i - 1].y, points[i].x, points[i].y);
    }
  }

  //create white borders to cut off extreme points
  noStroke(0);
  fill(220);
  rect(width - 50, 0, width, height);
  rect(width, height, width - 50, 0);
  rect(0, 0, width, 50);
  rect(0, height, width, -50);
  looper++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me!